# How to accesss hidden field in inner class (java)

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have the following problem.

```
class Master
{
   private String name;
   class Inner
   {
     private String name;
     private void printNames()
     {
       System.out.println("Master.name"+"Inner.name");
     }
   }
}
```

How can I access both name fields in the inner class without changing the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
System.out.println("Master.name: " + Master.this.name + 
                   " Master.Inner.name: " + this.name);
```

`Master.this.name` references the instance field of the outer class, `Master`, from within the inner class.

Comment: wow thanks. I don't understand why it would work like that but ok.

Comment: @ErikHosszú An instance of a non-static inner class is always related to an instance of the outer class. Thats why you can get a `this` from both. Check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).